# Why do we require flatness in the definition of an étale morphism

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

I am looking for some geometric reasoning why we require flatness in the definition of an étale morphism. If we have a morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$, it seems to me that the condition of being unramified removes the possibility of a fibre “jumping” in dimension however this seems to be the reason for requiring flatness. What problems can the condition of flatness solve that unramified can’t?

For example take the nodal cubic $X=V(y^2-x^3)$ projecting down to $Y=\mathbb{A}^1$. Then this morphism is unramified everywhere except the origin, then would we not also have a flatness away from the origin i.e. if we considered $U=V\backslash (0,0)$ and the morphism $f|_U:U\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1\backslash \{0\}$ would this not be flat?

Could someone also give an example of an unramified morphism that is not flat?

Comment: Closed immersions are unramified. They are flat (i.e., etale) if they are also open immersions.

Comment: This seems like you're really asking about [what flat means](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6789/why-are-flat-morphisms-flat), which to a first approximation is more or less "continuously varying fibers". The reason we like this is because an etale morphism is supposed to be the analogue of a covering map, where the fibers vary continuously. Just an unramified morphism would not give this.

Comment: @KReiser yes I really am struggling to see the meaning of flatness. So I have heard people say that flatness will give you continuously varying fibres, but I’m unsure how to deduce this from the algebraic definition of flatness.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar nice example! Thanks!

Comment: Read the link! Lots of words have been said about this by some very smart people there.